# Add and OLEObject after/in place of a particular string using Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I insert an OLE object in a Word document using the VBA code below.

```vb
Sub Test()
Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12", FileName _
  :="C:\Users\ananyroy\Documents\SDWAN\NRFUAutomation\Trials\TestFile.xlsx", LinkToFile _
  :=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
  "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe" _
  , IconIndex:=100, IconLabel:="Book1.xlsx", Range:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(4).Range
End Sub
```

I am looking for a method to add this OLE object after a particular string or in place of the placeholder string.
The Range parameter seems a tedious way to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Text = "Placeholder Text"
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        If .found Then
            rng.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12", FileName _
            :="C:\Users\ananyroy\Documents\SDWAN\NRFUAutomation\Trials\TestFile.xlsx", LinkToFile _
            :=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
            "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe" _
            , IconIndex:=100, IconLabel:="Book1.xlsx", Range:=rng
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And to insert *after* the found text add `rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` just before inserting the OLE Object.

Comment: Thank you Rich and Timothy :) this worked now :)

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post today. I wish to achieve similar result using Python. And here's the code (syntax) I wish to share here after numerous trials and errors.

This Python code snippet mimics the behavior of the VBA Macro discussed in the thread. The `**win32com**` library in Python allows manipulation of Word documents similar to Word VBA.

```py
# Insert text file as an object in the first table (Cell Position: Third Row, Fourth Column)
        table = doc.tables[0]
        cell = table.Cell(3, 4)

        # Get existing InlineShapes count in the cell
        existing_shapes_count = cell.Range.InlineShapes.Count
        
        # Define the current range
        range_to_move = cell.Range.InlineShapes(existing_shapes_count).Range
        range_to_move.Collapse(0) # Move to the end of the line
        
        range_to_move.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(
            ClassType="Package",
            FileName=os.path.abspath(text_file),
            DisplayAsIcon=True
        )
```

Hope this helps someone facing a similar challenge in the future!